# How to submit form and show result without reload?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms, submit

Let's say I have two divs in a document. The first one has controlling character and the second one should be used as a preview, the result of the user work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="workHere">
  <form id="workForm" action="php/create_pdf.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="c" id="inputId">
      // etc...
  </form>
</div>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

When the user insert some value, all these values in `#workForm` should be sent to `create_pdf_preview.php` and the result had to depict in `#preview`.

**JS + jQuery**

I tried to use `.load` jQuery method and actually it worked. But I don't know if I used it in right way and this solution looked unacceptable, cause there is the length limitation for the GET method and the execution was too complicated - I had to collect data to JS

```
`var datafield = document.getElementById("inputId").value;`
```

and then I could use it in `.load` method

```
$(".c").on('blur', function(){
  $("#preview").load("php/create_pdf_preview.php?data=" + datafield);
});
```

I know this is stupid way and also I know there are easier possibilities with AJAX or JSON, but this is still a wonderland for me and this is the reason why this question is posted. Could anyone please give me **some direction**? I'm not asking about any solution. Let ask me if I would evidence more details. Thank you very much.

Comment: can use `$.post` and insert the response yourself in success callback. Should also look at `serialize()` to simplify creating your data

Comment: @charlietfl, it looks that you adviced me right and I'm going to check it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `POST` for posting the data. `POST` can hold more data and thus you probably won't get exhausted easily with length of data.

Try -

```
$(".c").on('blur', function(){
    $.post( "php/create_pdf_preview.php", $( "#workForm" ).serialize())
    .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data posted: " + data );

        //print here 
        $("#preview").html(data);
    });
});
```

you can find it here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

or you can use the more detailed one - -

```
$(".c").on('blur', function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/create_pdf_preview.php",
      data: $( "#workForm" ).serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          alert( "Data posted: " + data );

          //print here 
          $("#preview").html(data);
      },
      dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
     });
});
```

you can also find it here - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi Mahmud, thank you very much. I'm going to try it, so I will accept answer if it will help me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, it alerts "Data posted: null". `$(".c")` selector selects every control textfield in the form, so `serialize()` collect them all? And how can I get the PDF in `success`? Thanks for response

Comment: You were using `$("#preview").load("php/create_pdf_preview.php?data=" + datafield);`, which means you are checking the `data` key in GET, did you change the php code accordingly to collect the values? Because in my code I am NOT sending as `data=`, instead using `serialize`, which will send the data directly from the form using the fields `name` as key. Check that all these are ok.

Comment: You are right! I didn't change GET method to POST. Now it alerts right values. But there is still question how the PDF could be previewed, because at this moment, in the PHP file, I'm echoing collected data but in the file with #workForm nothing is printed.

Comment: Anyway, the answer could be accepted, cause this solves the main problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. This is great, I appreciate this! Now I understand and it is the time to check mentioned functions and methods in reference. Thank you very much :)